# can't get "location" from response headers C#

Tags: c#, response-headers

[image]

there is a token in location, which I want to get

I tried this code

```
        Uri uri = new Uri(url);
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            AllowAutoRedirect = false
        };
        HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient(handler);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Referrer = uri;
        var responsee = httpclient.GetAsync(uri).Result;
        var location = responsee.Headers.GetValues("location").FirstOrDefault();
```

but I get only 12 header key

[image]

how can I get Location key?

Comment: In the screenshot we see a POST request but you do a GET request. You are also probably missing data that the POST request expects

Answer (score -1):

With C# .NET 7.0 you have a Location property you can access like this

```
var location = responsee.Headers.Location;
```